# Postgresql get the most common value in array

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table with column with array values (after group by and array_agg function)

```
COLUMN_VALUE          | other_columns...
-----------:          | -------:
 {0.45,0.45,0.97,0.99}|        ..
 {0.45,0.45,0.85,0.99}|        ..
 {0.45,0.45,0.77,0.99}|        ..
 {0.45,0.45,0.10,0.99}|        ..
```

How do I get the most frequent value? (0.45 for each row for this case)

My guess goes to unnest and groupby again but I am trying to find something more robust and faster.

Query I am using to build the table

```sql
select column1, column2, column3, array_agg(column4) as prices
from tb
where some conditions
group by 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: "*after group by and array_agg function*" - why don't you do it _during_ aggregation using `mode()`? Please **[edit]** your question and add the query you are currently using

Comment: I can't share the query since it contains info that I cannot share. I will try to explain better what I use. Not sure how to use mode but will edit my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the most frequent value during aggregation using the `mode()` aggregate:

```
select column1, column2, column3, 
       array_agg(column4) as prices
       mode() within group (order by column4 desc) as most_frequent_price
from tb
where ...
group by 1, 2, 3
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7d27d6859612b7d9e116d8e64851f4b5)

Comment: So basically I do not need to use that array_agg(column4). Any tips if we have two values with the frequent to take the highest/ smallest one?

Comment: @ShayHa: [quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE) "*arbitrarily choosing the first one if there are multiple equally-frequent results*". I don't know of a way to prioritize one over the other in that case

Comment: You can solve this by adding desc after column4 and then it will return the highest, else its order is asc so you get the lowest value. mode() within group (order by column4 desc)

Comment: @ShayHa: ah, I misunderstood your question. I thought you were asking about prioritizing one value over the other if you have two different values that appear the same number of times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unnest()` and some aggregation logic:

```
select t.*, m.mode
from t cross join lateral
     (select el as mode
      from unnest(t.column_value) el
      group by el
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 1
     ) m;
```

I've called this *mode* because that is the statistical term for the most common value.